# Performance implications of function call in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have an sql query which is something like below

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table where ID IN (SELECT * from dbo.function())
```

`dbo.function` returns a single column with multiple rows. There is no index on the table from which this function is fetching values as there are only 20 rows in that table.

Now my concern is can I put `SELECT * from dbo.function()` in complex joins statements or should I create a table variable and call function once to populate that table variable and use that in subsequent queries.

Are there any performance implications if I call the function in where clause ? Will the query engine optimize the query by populating the result from function only once or will it call the function for each row separately?

Comment: You should probably create a table variable or temporary table if you care about performance.  The optimizer has more information about tables than functions.

Comment: You can add the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` hint to make the the function deterministic and check if it complies with the SQL requirements by running `SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[function]'), 'IsDeterministic')`

Comment: If the function is returning multiple rows from a table with only 20 rows I would ask what benefit the function provides. Perhaps it isn't needed?

Comment: @SeanLange Its takes a parameter and based on which it returns the rows. It basically filter out from those 20 rows.

Comment: @RubensFarias It returns 0 for that query so that means its non-deterministic and can't be optimized ?

Comment: @kaysush deterministict means that for the same input function result is always the same

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński well that is true for my function but still I get 0 for that deterministic check query.

Comment: Is the function an inline or a multi-statement table-valuated function? (If it helps, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx shows the syntax difference between the two.)